# Searching for multiple strings in a file

Tags: powershell

I currently have the following

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include file.ext | Select-String -pattern "c:" | group path | select name | export-csv results.csv
```

If I wanted to find things with both "c:" and "d:" how would I write that logic?

Thanks

Comment: You can simplify the `group` and `select` part by using `select -unique path`. Although your column name in the CSV would change, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Select-String` takes a regex, so you can just use

```
Select-String '[cd]:'
```

which will match either `c:` or `d:`.

For more complex ones you can use an alternation construct:

```
Select-String '(mike|sally):'
```

Comment: and if it was the strings "mike" and "sally"?

Comment: I think you need to escape the pipe according to this: http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions#Example_-_Select-String

Comment: No. In that example it's used to match a literal `|`. If you want special characters in regex to still perform their special-ness you must not escape them.